# IE11 and a Javascript-based Modal Form Acting Funny

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-11

I have a WordPress plugin called [Easy Age Verifier](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-age-verifier) in the WordPress repository and got a [support request](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/doesnt-work-in-explorer-11?replies=2#post-8620399) that has me flat-out baffled. Here's his message:

> On Explorer 11 on Windows 10, the fields can't be filled in. Clicking in a field seems to activate a blinking text line somewhere way below the fields and typing numbers in does nothing. I can't include a link because the site is in development.

I installed Easy Beer Lister onto my test environment, and whudduya know? I get the same exact problem.

The code that runs this plugin can be seen in the [repository](https://github.com/tstandiford/easy-age-verifier), but I'll go ahead and put a copy of the code that creates the form here as well.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, can you point me in the direction on what causes it, and how I can fix it? Thank you!

```js
//For the max value of the input in the age form
taseavCurrDate = new Date();
if(taseavData.debug == true){
  var taseavDebugLog = [];
}

function taseavDebug(log){
  if(taseavData.debug == true){
    console.log(log);
    taseavDebugLog.push(log);
  }
  return
}

//Gets the cookie that was just stored
function taseavGetCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return false;
}

//The actual form
function taseavAgeForm(){
  var result;
  result =  "<div id='taseav-age-verify' class='" + taseavData.wrapperClass + "'>";
  result +=   "<form class='" + taseavData.formClass + "'>";
  result +=   "<h2>" + taseavData.formTitle + "</h2>";
  result +=     "<div class='taseav-month'>";
  result +=     "<label>Month</label>";
  result +=     "<input name='month' type='number' min='1' max='12' required>";
  result +=     "</div>";
  result +=     "<div class='taseav-day'>";
  result +=     "<label>Day</label>";
  result +=     "<input name='day' type='number' min='1' max='31' required>";
  result +=     "</div>";
  result +=     "<div class='taseav-year'>";
  result +=     "<label>Year</label>";
  result +=     "<input name='year' type='number' min='1900' max='"+ taseavCurrDate.getFullYear() +"' required>";
  result +=     "</div>";
  result +=     "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
  result +=   "</form>";
  result +=  "</div>";
  return result;
}

//Stores the age into a cookie
function taseavStoreAge(){
  var month = jQuery('#taseav-age-verify input[name="month"]').val();
  var day = jQuery('#taseav-age-verify input[name="day"]').val();
  var year = jQuery('#taseav-age-verify input[name="year"]').val();
  if(month < 10){
    month = "0" + month;
  }
  if(day < 10){
    day = "0" + day;
  }
  var result = "taseavdob=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  document.cookie = result;
  taseavDebug('Age stored as a cookie. Value = ' + result);
}

function taseavGetAge() {
    taseavDebug('Evaluated Date of Birth: ' +taseavGetCookie('taseavdob'));
    var birthday = new Date(taseavGetCookie('taseavdob'));
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

function taseavIsAboveAge(ageToCheck){
  if(!ageToCheck){
    taseavDebug('Getting minimum age to check...')
    ageToCheck = taseavData.minAge;
    taseavDebug('Age to check: ' + taseavData.minAge);
  };
  taseavDebug('Getting evaluated age to check against...')
  var age = taseavGetAge();
  taseavDebug('Age checked: ' + age);
  if(age < ageToCheck){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}

function confirmAge(){
  if(taseavIsAboveAge() == false){
    taseavDebug('User is underage. Displaying message "' + taseavData.underageMessage + '"');
    alert(taseavData.underageMessage);
    if(taseavData.debug == true){
      alert(taseavDebugLog.join('\n \n'));
    }
    history.back();
  }
  else{
    taseavDebug('User is older than the min age of ' + taseavData.minAge +'. Removing age verify overlay.');
    jQuery('#taseav-age-verify').remove();
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("html").append(taseavAgeForm());
    jQuery("#taseav-age-verify form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    //Disables mouse-wheel when gallery is open
    jQuery("#taseav-age-verify").bind("mousewheel", function() {
         return false;
    });
    jQuery('#taseav-age-verify').submit(function(){
      taseavStoreAge();
      confirmAge();
      taseavDebug(taseavData);
  });
})
```

```css
.taseav-age-verify {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:9999;
}

.taseav-age-verify form {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width:600px;
    width:90%;
}

.taseav-age-verify input{
  width:calc(100% - 24px);
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.taseav-age-verify div{
  margin-bottom:20px;
  max-width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.taseav-age-verify .taseav-month{
    width:24%;
}

.taseav-age-verify .taseav-day{
    width:24%;
}

.taseav-age-verify .taseav-year{
    width:50%;
}

.taseav-age-verify div:nth-of-type(2){
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
}

.taseav-age-verify input[type="submit"]{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

.taseav-age-verify{
  color:white;
}

.taseav-age-verify label{
  color:white;
}

.taseav-age-verify h2{
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) seems to indicate that IE11 support for `type="number"` is a bit dodgy, but I'm not sure if that's causing your problem.

Comment: I'm gonna guess it's a css conflict. Have you tested in ie11? I dare say you have. I have seen this before yonks ago so can't remember the problem / solution.

Comment: @CarolMcKay I tested it in IE11, and got the same issues he has. Honestly I didn't test this when I launched it (shame on me. I know better than that.).  If you happen to think about what caused it please let me know!

Comment: @gcampbell - Yeah, I had a feeling it may be related to that too. Perhaps there's a workaround.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of position:relative; curing all sorts of evils (even on floated elements) on the older ie browsers. Also display either block or table sometimes worked as a cludge.

Comment: Any chance you could include a complete, runnable, example?

Comment: The best I can do is link you to my demo site that runs the plugin, which can be seen here: http://brewio.alexstandiford.com/ @jrummell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please either wrap your label around your input, or give the input an id and use the "for" property on your label, where the value is the id of the input.

This will help you with your focus issues and make your form accessible.

Comment: Dually noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was I appended code after the 'html' tag, instead of the 'body' tag.

Here's what I originally had:

```
jQuery("html").append(taseavAgeForm());
```

Here's what I had to change it to:

```
jQuery("body").append(taseavAgeForm());
```